# Residual characters printed on stdout with socket communication

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, system-calls

In a socket TCP communication, I have a server and a client. Both can read from and write to the socket.

The code is written in C and uses Linux system calls `recv` and `write`.

`recv` saves the received string in:

```
char message_array[2000];
```

Another array with the same dimensions is used as source for the `write` process.

After both the reading and writing process the following operation is performed, to clear all the array elements:

```
memset(&message_array, 0, sizeof(message_array));
```

Moreover, a `fflush` is performed on `stdin` and `stdout` at every write and every read process.

The server prints on its `stdout` what it writes and what it receives.

If I send small messages from both the terminals ("hello", "hi") even for several times (18-20), all appears to work correctly. But if I try to send longer messages (longer than 5 characters, but shorter than 2000!), the server side has some strange behaviour: it prints the message received from the client, but then it inserts a random number of the trailing characters of the previous messages. For example I have:

```
CLIENT MESSAGE: hello1
SERVER MESSAGE: hello2
CLIENT MESSAGE: hello3
SERVER MESSAGE: hello4 
CLIENT MESSAGE: some other characters5
SERVER MESSAGE: hello6
CLIENT MESSAGE: a long phrase 7
ters5
```

After several messages, the 5 characters `ters5` from a **previous** message appear as trailing characters after the actual message, which was just `a long phrase 7`.
Continuing the "conversation", other unexpected newline and "old" characters appears on the `stdout` of the server.

The code of the read and write routine is the following:

```
void *connection_handler_read(void *socket_read_desc)
{
    int read_sock = *(int*)socket_read_desc;
    int read_size;
    char remote_message[MAX_STRING_LEN];

    while( (read_size = recv(read_sock, remote_message, MAX_STRING_LEN, 0)) > 0 )
    {
        printf(remote_message);
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    free(socket_read_desc);
    connection_active = 0;
    return 0;
}

void *connection_handler_write(void *socket_write_desc)
{
    int write_sock = *(int*)socket_write_desc;
    char local_message[MAX_STRING_LEN];

    while( connection_active != 0 )
    {
        scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", local_message);
        write(write_sock, local_message, strlen(local_message));
        memset(&local_message, 0, sizeof(local_message));
        fflush(stdin);
    }

    free(socket_write_desc);
    return 0;
}
```

These two functions are invoked in the `main` as threads with `pthread_create` after a new socket connection is succesfully created (so, after a successful `accept`). They obviously operate on the same socket.

My questions are:

1) Is this a software problem or a socket problem?

2) Which trick should I have followed, in addition to `memset` and `fflush`?

Comment: A couple of things stand out to me: The first is that you say you call `memset` *after* writing/reading? The second is that doing `fflush(stdin)` is technically undefined behavior. Also, please try to show us the code you use to send and receive *and* print, preferably try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us (it's said that a picture says more than a thousand words, well it's the same with code).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes, I call `memset` *after* reading/writing, so (in my intentions) when the contents of the array is no more useful and it needs to be cleared. The whole program, even if minimal, is too long, but I will try to include at least the read and write routines.

Comment: 'printf(remote_message);' called on a buffer that is not guaranteed null-terminated.  Cargo-cult memset instead of correctly utilizing the value returned by send/recv to insert a terminating null.  Probably other bugs centred around misunderstanding of null-terminated char arrays.

Comment: @MartinJames maybe due to your experience, you concentrated a lot of informations in few lines. First of all: if `write_size` was the value returned by `write`, should I perform `memset(&local_message, 0, write_size);`? And are you meaning that the array `remote_message` may not be null-terminated?

Answer (score 2):

1. The read side does not zero the buffer used for reading, before reusing it. Do `char remote_message[MAX_STRING_LEN] = {0};` at declaration time and `memset(remote_message, 0, sizeof(remote_message);` after reading.
2. `memset(&local_message, 0, sizeof(local_message));` -->  `memset(local_message, 0, sizeof(local_message));`
3. Bear in mind TCP (are you using TCP?) is not a message oriented protocol. The `read()` can (and eventually will) return any amount of data between 1 byte and the amount sent by the writer so far. If you want a line oriented protocol/output, scan the read data for '\n' AND do not remove it in your `scanf()`.

Other:

- Do you call `close()` on the socket descriptors somewhere?
- Why do you free the `int *` parameters? Are they really allocated from the heap with malloc?

Comment: 'memset(remote_message, 0, sizeof(remote_message); after reading' - why?  The read/recv calls return the number of bytes read.  You only need to insert one nul at that index to ensure that text data received is correctly terminated, (though this does mean oversizing the buffer by 1, compared to the read length, to be sure of leaving enough space).

Comment: @thuovila Yes, I'm using TCP as specified in the beginning of the question. Thank you for the advices about it. No, I don't call `close()` on the socket. And yes, in `main` the parameters are allocated with `malloc` before the creation of threads.

Comment: @MartinJames I realize memsetting the whole buffer is somewhat less efficient, but I also think it is less error prone. The OP was already using memset and I dont think the difference in efficiency matters much at this level of programming.

Answer (score 2):

In `connection_handler_read()` you read `strlen()` characters and you don't `memset()` buffer to `'\0'`. `strlen()` characters is all you send in `connection_handler_write()` and it doesn't count trailing `'\0'`. On the read side buffer might contain some uninitialized characters.

Comment: Yes, 99.9% of all C network code with strlen() in it uses it incorrectly.

Comment: @smbear ok for memset: I need to make it also for `connection_handler_read`. So, you would advice to make `memset(&local_message, 0, strlen(local_message));` instead of `memset(&local_message, 0, sizeof(local_message));`?

Comment: `memset(&local_message, 0, strlen(local_message));` is rather unusual construct.

Comment: Also, as @thuovila has written, TCP isn't message oriented protocol, so you should take into consideration number of bytes received. There is another problem: you perform `scanf()` to buffer without considering buffer size - one can easily write beyond limits of buffer causing stack corruption.